# Advanced JavaScript design patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, books

I'm looking for books, online resources or suggestions about how to structure big projects or build a framework in JavaScript.

I'm not looking for books explaining how inheritance or closures work. I'm more looking for design patterns and techniques to organize (and develop) complex applications.

At the moment I found:

- this old topic [Advanced javascript guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920671/advanced-javascript-guidance)
- the pdf [Building A JavaScript Framework](http://dailyjs.com/files/build-a-javascript-framework.pdf)
- the article [Let's Make a Framework: Library Architecture](http://dailyjs.com/2010/02/25/djscript-part-1-structure/)

Any other suggestion?

Comment: I think this one is really well written... http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Comment: How about [JavaScript Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752)?

Comment: Have you read that book? Can you vouch for it being good

Comment: @Raynos I own it, but I haven't spent much time with it. From what I'm able to tell, it's solid. It explains a bunch of interesting patterns I haven't seen mentioned in other books/articles (patterns like Observer, Mediator, Proxy, Strategy, but also all the core patterns like Facade, Factory, Singleton, Sandbox, Module, Curry), so I consider it worth buying.

Comment: The advanced chapters seem interesting

Comment: Hi Ghigo, I'm sorry this was migrated here unnecessarily, but creating a list of places you can find JavaScript design patterns is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange style of Q&A. If there's a specific problem you're working on that you'd like help with, feel free to ask about that, instead.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO (driven by my experience)..

If you want to learn abstract concepts, concentrate on the abstract concept. In other words, if you're looking at design patterns, read books such as [GOF's Design Patterns book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). Check out [Wikipedia's Software Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) page. Learn them. Love them.

If you want to learn Javascript, read [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Learning and understanding the spec will help you in becoming an expert with the language.

**Then..**

You won't be asking these questions (not that there's anything wrong with them). You'll have a solid understanding of both areas and will be able to implement anything you need relatively trivially.